# Extracting Range and Sending List to Integers 01054 Python

Tags: python, list, sum, range, average

I want to create a program that asks for three numbers, then displays the range, sum of the numbers in that range, and average of the numbers in the range. Why is it that this program is not able to interpret the list as integers?

```
numbers = list() 
for i in range(0, 3): 
    inputNr = int(input("Enter a number: "))

    numbers.append(inputNr)

rangeofNums = range(numbers)
sumRange = 


print("The range is: " + rangeofNums)
print("The total sum is: " + sumRange)
print("The avg is: " + avgRange)
```

Comment: `range()` takes up to 3 args, none of which is a list. You can use `*` to expand the list, e.g. `range(*numbers)`. However, the 3 args are `start, stop, step` are you sure that is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

The `range` function takes in one, two or three integer arguments, not a list. Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) about `range`. If you want to make a range using the minimun and maximum numbers provided by user, you should do:

```
range_of_nums = range(min(l), max(l) + 1)
```

This produces a range that includes both the minimum and maximum of inputs as well as all numbers between them. Also you should use `format` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=format#str.format)) or `f string literals` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings)) when printing. All in all:

```
numbers = list() 
for i in range(0, 3): 
    inputNr = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    numbers.append(inputNr)

range_of_nums = range(min(numbers), max(numbers) + 1)
sum_range = sum(range_of_nums)
avg_range = sum_range / len(range_of_nums)

print("The range is: {}".format(range_of_nums))
print("The total sum is: {}".format(sum_range))
print("The avg is: {}".format(avg_range))
```